# bokeh horizontal scroll none

Tags: python, scroll, rect, segment, bokeh

I'm bokeh user, bokeh is good tools.

I use the 'segment' function for graph, this graph is very wide

so I use the plot_width=3000 option. but, graph is over display,

if I want to see all graph, I save the graph using 'prevew/save' option or 'pan' option

I want to use the horizontal scroll bar, what do you think about this

help me...

```
segment(param_seq_array_shift, (box_array[cnt, 5]-box_array[cnt,                
            6])*length_standard/box_array[cnt, 8]+lower_standard, param_seq_array_shift,   
           (box_array[cnt, 3]-box_array[cnt, 6])*length_standard/box_array[cnt, 
            8]+lower_standard, x_range = param_seq_array_name,
            tools="pan,hover,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,previewsave", title=file_list[cnt],
            plot_width=3000, plot_height=400,
            #source = source,
            line_width=0.5, line_color="black")
```